# Reasons for lvling up in GW2?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I'm kind of new to GW2, I have 5 characters lvl 1-20, and just now I found out the PvP button, that lets you go to a PvP world where you are max lvl with all the traits and skills and can buy the best items for free.

So I was wondering, what reasons are there to even bother lvling up to lvl 80? Can I get any stronger than what I see in the PvP world?

I know lvling up can be fun and I enjoy it, but I need to know what other reasons (if any) are there.

Comment: Isn't it kind of ridiculous that the description of the reason for marking this question as a duplicate says that, if the answers to the other don't fully address the question (which they don't), one should ask a new question...? For someone who is new to the game, this is a valid question, I think, even if the answer may seem obvious to those of us who've been playing for a while.

Answer (score 8):

**If all you care about is the structured PvP, then there isn't a point.**

Leveling in PvE does nothing to make you stronger in sPvP (*nothing* will make you stronger there; they've tried to make the playing field as level as possible), so if that's the only aspect of the game you're interested in, then no, there isn't much of a reason to level up in PvE.

However, there are other reasons to level up in PvE:

- seeing more content: the first dungeon isn't accessible until level 30, the story runs all the way to level 80, and at level 20 you'll be able to survive in less than half of the zones, so if you want to see everything the game has to offer, you'll need to hit the level cap
- becoming stronger in WvWvW: the other PvP format, world vs world, will scale you up to 80, but it doesn't do it in the same way that the PvP arenas do; leveling up in PvE will absolutely make you stronger in WvWvW, since it will unlock trait points, skill points, and help you find better equipment (you can, of course, level up solely in WvWvW if you so desire)

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain?

Comment: @ObloviousSage No.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz: +1 from me to compensate for an illogical downvote, then. It's a better, more detailed answer than the accepted answer to the "duplicate" one (which was closed as non-constructive even though its essence could have been rescued).